# Load event not working while used with a selector element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Below is my `<script>` tag:

```
var2=document.querySelector('html')

var2.addEventListener('load',function(){alert('yo')});
```

why is `onload` not working?

And this is not just with `html` tag but with basically any selector.

Comment: `load` does not fire on the 'html' element. Try `window.addEventListener('load', function() ...)`. Given your update: '*And this is not just with html tag but with basically any selector*', that's because very few elements fire the `load` event. `window`, `img` and `svg` are the only ones which spring to mind. What exactly is the goal of the code, as there's likely to be a better approach.

Comment: No mate , check out the edits i made to the question .Basically i am able to use it like this window.onload=function(){alert('yo1');} but 
in format of addEventListener doesnt matter with which element i use 'load' event with it's not working ...

Comment: Allright given the update to your answer ,i think i found a sense of satisfaction.
And no,i was just trying to learn about events and it wasnt for any specific purpose.
This list of elements, only with whom we could use 'load' event could you share a link to any document lementing it ? Thanx a ton already mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elements don't load content (the obvious exceptions being `<iframe>` and `<img>`) so load events don't fire on them.

If you want to capture the page's load event, then you shouldn't bind to any element:

```
addEventListener("load", yourEventHandlerFunction);
```

Comment: Just to add to @quentin answer if you are not binding this to any element it means it is getting attached to window.